# Delete garbage parts of strings in MySQL

Tags: mysql

One of my fields contains a strange section of text, but there is something in it that is important for me:
EX:  my field is something like this:

> \"'Way Out\"(How to be one) (1961) {Side Show (#1.12)}\"'t Schaep Met
>   De 5 Pooten\"

All the text is garbage, I just want 1961.
Also, my table has more than 200K rows.

The year is inside of the parentheses. The query which is shown below works at every position, but when I have something inside of parentheses before year there is a problem.
All of the text is garbage but the year is required. I already used:

```
UPDATE `myTable`
SET `myField` = (SUBSTRING_INDEX(`myField`, '(', -3));
UPDATE `myTable`
SET `myField` = (SUBSTRING_INDEX(`myField`, ')', 3));
UPDATE `myTable`
SET `myField` = (SUBSTRING_INDEX(`myField`, ')', 2));
UPDATE `myTable`
SET `myField` = (SUBSTRING_INDEX(`myField`, ')', 1));
```

Is there any way to make a query that saves just the value inside of any parentheses which contain 4 digits?
In the above ex the result should be: 1961

Comment: is it possible to have multiple 4digits string in a single column?

Comment: no, the only 4digits string is the year and it's uniqe in every row

Comment: Talk about bad database design... I don't know how you got this database but I would first normalize it. Might also improve query performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may give it a try ( I guess it's a one time job hence leave the performance issue):

```
UPDATE myTable MT

CROSS JOIN 
(
    Select (th*1000+h*100+t*10+u+1) x from
    (select 0 th union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
    select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) A,
    (select 0 h union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
    select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) B,
    (select 0 t union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
    select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) C,
    (select 0 u union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
    select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) D
    WHERE (th*1000+h*100+t*10+u+1) >= 1800
    AND (th*1000+h*100+t*10+u+1) <= 3000
    order by x
) t
SET MT.myField = t.x
WHERE `myField` LIKE CONCAT('%',t.x,'%');
```

**Note:** Assuming your year string is within this range : `from 1800 to 3000`

Better put your minimum and maximum year in the where clause

`WHERE (th*1000+h*100+t*10+u+1) >= MINIMUM_YEAR
    AND (th*1000+h*100+t*10+u+1) <= MAXIMUM_YEAR`

**Before running the above query:**

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac94d/1/0).

**After running the above query:**

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7272d/1/0)

Comment: It caused this error: "[Err] 1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction"           but when I used it in a small table with about 1000 row it worked. but my table has 656024 row

Comment: I restarted mysql service and tried this command again, it worked perfectly

Comment: May be some other process locked the records. And obviously this update would take longer time than usual while updating. That's why I mentioned the words **performance issue** somewhere in my answer. Btw, sounds great that it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks @BerndBuffen. I thought I was going to encounter down votes because of this approach.

Answer (score 1):

If there only is one 4 digit value in (xxxx) so you can use **REGEXP_REPLACE**, but i am not sure is it only in MariaDB

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE( 
    "Way Out\"(How to be one) (1961) {Side Show (#1.12)}\"'t Schaep Met De 5 Pooten"
    , '^(.*) \\(([0-9]{4})\\) (.*)$'
    , '\\2'
  ) AS VAL;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> SELECT
    ->   REGEXP_REPLACE(
    ->     "Way Out\"(How to be one) (1961) {Side Show (#1.12)}\"'t Schaep Met De 5 Pooten"
    ->     , '^(.*) \\(([0-9]{4})\\) (.*)$'
    ->     , '\\2'
    ->   ) AS VAL;
+------+
| VAL  |
+------+
| 1961 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourSchema]>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but I've got this error:                  [Err] 1305 - FUNCTION product.REGEXP_REPLACE does not exist

Comment: `MYSQL ` doesn't support `REGEXP_REPLACE`. @ArashRabiee

Comment: @Arash Rabiee - if you only need this one time, you can me send a zip SQL file and i will change it for you quick in MariaDB. This not the solution for your problem

Answer (score 1):

If the structure of the string is fixed, you can search for the closing bracket ) and then the opening bracket ( first:

```
select substring_index(text, ') (', -1)
```

then you can get the part of this substring before the first open bracket:

```
select
  substring_index(
    substring_index(text, ') (', -1),
    ')',
    1
  )
```

Comment: No the stracture is not fix, the only fixed part is that there is only one 4digits inside the pranthesis